# Invalid email or password error when testing devise sign in with RSpec feature spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I keep getting `Invalid email or password.` error in RSpec feature test when I try to test sign in implemented using Devise.

**spec/features/signing_in_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'Signing in' do
  let!(:user) { create :user }

  scenario 'signs in user with valid credentials', js: true do
    visit '/users/sign_in'

    fill_in 'Email', with: user.email
    fill_in 'Password', with: user.password
    click_button 'Sign in'

    expect(page).to have_content 'Dashboard'
  end
end
```

**spec/factories/users.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email 'user@mail.com'
    password '12345678'
    password_confirmation '12345678'

    factory :admin do
      email 'admin@mail.com'
    end
  end
end
```

I already verified that user is saved into DB and that sing in works in development.

Comment: Are you using capybara for this..?
https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara

Comment: Yes I am using capybara with poltergeist.

Comment: Are you include this require 'capybara/rspec' in your rspec helper

Comment: Yes and it's obviously not a problem with capybara. Other test passes and capybara DSL works just fine.

Answer (score 6):

I actually had the same issue

this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara helped me.

I had to add this file to my support folder

https://github.com/railscasts/391-testing-javascript-with-phantomjs/blob/master/checkout-after/spec/support/share_db_connection.rb

Comment: this was helpful in my case!

Answer (score 0):

I believe after you created your `user` record, the field `password` does not have its original value anymore. So try, instead of

```
fill_in 'Password', with: user.password
```

to use

```
fill_in 'Password', with: '12345678'
```

**EDIT**

You need to call `skip_confirmation!` on your user record, update your factory like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email 'user@mail.com'
    password '12345678'
    password_confirmation '12345678'

    factory :admin do
      email 'admin@mail.com'
    end

    ignore { confirm_user true }

    after(:build) do |object, evaluator|
      object.skip_confirmation! if evaluator.confirm_user
    end
  end
end
```

If ever you need in another test to create a user without confirming it, you can call `create :user, confirm_user: false`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help either. I'm not using confirmable module of Devise so there is no need to confirm user after he's created.

Comment: so I don't know. sorry

Answer (score -1):

You can update specs like this:

```
describe "the signin process", :type => :feature do
  before :each do
    User.make(:email => 'user@example.com', :password => 'caplin')
  end

  it "signs me in" do
    visit '/sessions/new'
    within("#session") do
      fill_in 'Login', :with => 'user@example.com'
      fill_in 'Password', :with => 'password'
    end
    click_link 'Sign in'
    expect(page).to have_content 'Success'
  end
end
```

Comment: What should User.make() do? Did you think User.create()? If so, I've already tried and it dind't solve my issue. And anyway I want to use factory girl.